# How would I convert a number in a certain format to an integer?

Tags: php

I have a funciton which returns the hours of a timestamp using 24 hour time

e.g.

03, 04, 12, 15

I want to be able to remove the 0 from the integer so instead of 03 I get 3..

Is there a quick function to do this or do I have to use a switch statement?

Comment: what does your function that returns the hours look like? It might be better to change it there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "010";
$num = (int)$str;
```

or

```
echo intval('042');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php):

```
$i = intval('03', 10);
```

Or [cast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) the string to an integer:

```
$s = '03';
$i = (int)$s;
```

Comment: Specifying the base isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
 $value = intval('02');
```

Answer (score 0):

Post your function for getting the formatted time. For example, you could use the non-leading zeroes `G` instead of `H`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

consider 07, is the value you're getting,

```
$val=07; 
echo intval($val);
```

Comment: that's not correct. your function will return a wrong result. the int value should be in quotes, like so $var = "07"

Comment: No, i've checked it before posting here. i'm using php 5.3.5, so it outputs 7 exactly....

Comment: @blejzz: Yeah! I've seen the examples. but they've given it for 32 bit version examples. But i tested locally and have no problems, any way we go with the rule. Thanks for pointing it out.